# Разница между SqlParameters.Add и AddWithValue

Tags: c#, sql-server

В чем разница между применением `SqlParameters.Add` и `SqlParameters.AddWithValue` для `SqlCommand`? Понятно что для первого случая мы первоначально указываем тип передаваемого параметра. Но не совсем понятно как функционирует `SqlParameters.AddWithValue`, допустим мы передадим туда параметр типа `int`

```
SqlParameters.AddWithValue("@myInt", 1)
```

В этом случае он передаст единицу как строковую переменную? И уже на сервере будет производится преобразование? Или будет определен тип параметра и уже приведен к параметру поля на сервере? На каком основании тогда происходит приведение? Например есть какая-нибудь таблица соответствия типов ms sql и c#? И какой вариант предпочтительней и почему (есть ли "подводные" камни)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть ответ на общем [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13733038/4535033):

> According to the MSDN:
>
> > AddWithValue replaces the SqlParameterCollection.Add method that takes
> >     a String and an Object. The overload of Add that takes a string and an
> >     object was deprecated because of possible ambiguity with the
> >     SqlParameterCollection. Add overload that takes a String and a
> >     SqlDbType enumeration value where passing an integer with the string
> >     could be interpreted as being either the parameter value or the
> >     corresponding SqlDbType value. Use AddWithValue whenever you want to
> >     add a parameter by specifying its name and value.
>
> So the AddWithValue replaces deprecated overload that create
>   ambiguity.

По-русски:

> AddWithValue пришёл на замену SqlParameterCollection.Add чтобы
>   исключить неоднозначность перегруженного метода Add, который принимает
>   String и Object. Потому что при передаче Integer может быть трактовано
>   как значение параметра или как значение SqlDbType.

Поэтому, где возможно используйте AddWithValue.

Answer (score 1):

AddWithValue заменяет метод SqlParameterCollection.Add , принимающий String и Object. Перегруженной версией метода Add, принимающая строку и объект пренебрегали из-за возможного конфликта с перегруженной версией SqlParameterCollection.Add, принимающей String и значение из перечисления SqlDbType, поскольку передача целого значения в строке может интерпретироваться как значение параметра или соответствующее значение SqlDbType. Используйте AddWithValue, когда требуется добавить параметр, задав его имя и значение.

Answer (score 1):

`AddWithValue` выводит соответствующий тип из значения переданного объекта.

Таблица соответствия есть в MSDN, в описании [`SqlDbType Enumeration`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype(v=vs.110).aspx)

Сам по себе отдельный метод добавлен только ради разрешения неоднозначности в перегрузке метода `Add` - между `Add(string parameterName, object value)` и `Add(string parameterName, SqlDbType sqlDbType)`.