# WinForms: Добавление значений в DataGridView c подключенной Sql таблицей

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

На форме есть элемент `DataGridView`, в которой есть подключенная `SQL` таблица. Также на форме имеется несколько элементов для ввода данных и кнопка, при нажатии на которую должен выполняться непосредственно процесс добавления данных. У меня ошибок нет, но при этом данные не вводятся. Заранее спасибо. Вот код:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Configuration;
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Курсовая.Приложение
{
    public partial class ProfileForm : Form
    {
        public ProfileForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void ProfileForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TouristGridView.DataSource = GetTouristList();
        }
        private DataTable dtTourist = new DataTable();
        private DataTable GetTouristList()
        {
            string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbx"].ConnectionString;
            using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connString))
            {
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT FIO AS 'ПІП', dob AS 'Дата народження', phone AS 'Номер телефону' FROM tourist", con))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    dtTourist.Load(reader);
                }
            }
            return dtTourist;
        }
        private void btnSearch(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            MySqlCommand Command = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO [tourist] ([ФИО], [Дата рождения], [Номер телефона]) VALUES ('" + NametextBox.Text + "','" + dobDate.Value + "','" + PhonetextBox.Text + "')");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понимаю, добавление данных должно происходить в процедуре btnSearch()?

Тогда - все довольно понятно.

попробую объяснить, пользуясь только Вашим собственным кодом:

смотрим на ту часть, колторая работает:

там есть такая штука, которая создаёт коннекшн к базе данных

```
    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connString))
```

и есть такое место, где этот коннекш открывается

```
    con.Open();
```

А в том месте, где у Вас должно происходить добавление данных - васего этого нет, есть только создание команды, которая должна добавить новые данные.

Следовательно, попробуем поменять код так:

```
    private void btnSearch(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbx"].ConnectionString;
        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connString))
        {
            con.Open();
            MySqlCommand Command = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO [tourist] ([ФИО], [Дата рождения], [Номер телефона]) VALUES ('" + NametextBox.Text + "','" + dobDate.Value + "','" + PhonetextBox.Text + "')");
            Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

Это - уже имеет все шансы на то, чтобы работать. По крайней мере, данные будут добавляться.

Но у этого кода я вижу еще 3 недостатка:

1. при добавлении данных Вы этого не увидите на экране. Потому что данные добавлятся в базу данных, но информация, отображенная на экране, при этом не обновится. Хорошо бы заново вызвать метод  ProfileForm_Load(), или каким то другим совособом "дернуть" процедуру, которая заново нарисует на экране данные, только что полученные из базы
2. строка коннекта к базе в коде дублируется. Она, конечно, берется из ConfigurationManager - но всё равно, можно вынести её куда то в "глобальные переменные".
3. Не очень хорошая практика - "клеить" запрос, используя при этом строковые значения полей. Это нехорошо по нескольким причинам: по первых, `sql injection`. Это само по себе интересно, почитайте. Во вторых, там могут быть пустые строки на месте незаполненных полей, что может приводить к ошибкам. И, наконец, типы данных: например, дата - это штука, которая зависит от location, и еще и от того, как именно напишет её пользователь.

Поэтому в тех случаях, когда надо в команду "зафигачить" параметры - используют конструкцию такого типа:

```
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", r_id);
```

**Дополнение.**

Очень опытный участник форума **aepot** обратил внимание на то, что в смысле использования .AddWithValue() - я даю плохой совет.

Это утверждение встречалось мне настолько часто, что я провел небольшие изыскания, и нашел исходную короткую статью, которая, вроде  бы, раскрывает смысл утверждения "AddWithValue - зло".

я перевел это в силу своего понимания, получилось вот что:

-начало перевода-

Оригинал:
https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

**Можно уже прекратить пользоваться AddWithValue?**

Это нужно прекратить.

Есть проблема с функцией AddWithValue: она должна по переданному значению определить соответсвующий SQL Type в базе данных. Но вот в чем дело:  иногда она ошибается...
Это особенно часто происходит при работе с Object arrays или аналогичными, где часть важной информации, которую ADO.Net использует для определения типа, отсутствует. Однако, это может случаться даже тогда, когда .Net type известен. Простейший пример: какой тип должен получиться на стороне базы данных из параметра, тип которого - string: VarChar, NVarChar или Char? Date или DateTime - другой пример.

Хорошая новость заключается в том, что в большинстве случаев эти несоответствия типов не имеют значения. Но иногда они действительно имеют значение, и даже большое значение.

Например, предположим, что у вас есть столбец базы данных varchar, но вы отправляете строковый параметр с помощью функции AddWithValue(). ADO.Net отправит это в базу данных как значение nvarchar. Базе данных **не разрешено** неявно преобразовывать ваш параметр nvarchar в значение varchar, чтобы оно соответствовало типу столбца для запроса. Понятно, почему: это будет сужающее преобразование, которое может привести к потере информации из исходного значения (поскольку в параметре могут быть нелатинские символы), и если это произойдет - база данных может выдать неправильные результаты запроса. Вместо этого базе данных, вероятно, потребуется преобразовать столбец varchar в nvarchar для этого запроса (что представляет собой расширяющее преобразование, которое гарантированно не потеряет информацию). Проблема в том, что это преобразование нужно будет сделать для каждой строки вашей таблицы.

Такое преобразование может произойти и с другими комбинациями типов. Например, колонка базы, содержащая тип Date может быть "расширена" до C#-типа DateTime. И даже страшно представить, что произойдет при несоответствии типа Data или числового типа на стороне базы данных, и типа string со стороны C#. Даже с nvarchar или nchar Вы можете обнаружить, что длины не совпадают, и, таким образом, для каждого значение в базе нужно модифицировать длинну строки.

Если такие операции кажутся вам дорогостоящими (потенциальные преобразования во время выполнения для данных в таблице, возможно, содержащей миллионы строк), вы правы. Да. Но это только начало. Эти недавно преобразованные значения теперь технически не совпадают со значениями, хранящимися в любых индексах, которые могут использовать этот столбец, что делает эти индексы бесполезными для выполнения вашего запроса. Теперь мы действительно бьем ниже пояса. Использование индексов существенно снижает производительность базы данных. Неспособность попасть в индекс может быть разницей между запросом, занимающим часы или секунды, между запросом, занимающим минуты, или мгновенным возвратом. А все началось с AddWithValue...

Но что вы должны сделать вместо этого? **Решение состоит в том, чтобы знать базовый тип базы данных, который вам нужен, а затем создать параметр запроса, который использует именно этот тип.**

Вот пример использования базы данных типа DateTime:

```
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Parameter", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = MyDateTimeVariable;
```

Вот другой пример, использования decimal(11,4):

```
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Parameter", SqlDbType.Decimal, 11, 4).Value = MyDecimalVariable;
```

Обратите внимание, что хотя это немного длиннее, это все еще одна строка кода. Вот и все. Это простое изменение в том, как вы определяете параметры, потенциально может сэкономить значительные потери производительности.

-конец перевода-

Мой краткий вывод:

вообще говоря, совет, данный в конце статьи "используйте максимально близкие типы в коде C# и в базе данных" - довольно очевиден. Со своей стороны, я бы сказал немного иначе: "если вы *хорошо понимаете*, что делаете, то использование .AddWithValue() ничем не отличается от использования Add() с явно указанным типом. Но если есть шанс перепутать, или этот код попадёт в руки другому человеку, который не будет фанатично следить за соответсвием типов - лучше не использовать .AddWithValue()".

По крайней мере, теперь мы лучше знаем, в чем  именно состоит зло .AddWithValue().

Comment: `AddWithValue` - [зло](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: @aepot - вы правы, и я постарался написать в ответе, почему именно :-)

Comment: Будет здорово создать отдельную тему про AddWithValue. Задать вопрос, почему это плохо и в ответе поместить перевод с собственными выводами. Тогда на эту тему можно будет давать ссылки.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov  - Вы правы, в вопросе ( https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/453170/ ) , который был задан здесь же 6 лет назад - мало толку, ответы крайне куцые. Попробую вечером последодвать Вашему совету!