# C# WinFroms "Ошибка синтаксиса в инструкции INSERT INTO."

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, ms-access

Я пытаюсь добавить новую запись в бд через форму, но при нажатии на кнопку появляется ошибка в строке с query. Никак не могу понять, что делаю не так..

```
  string region = dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
  string country = dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
  var in2021= float.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
  var in2022 = float.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[3].Value.ToString());

  dbConnection.Open();
  string query = "INSERT INTO Таблица (Регион, [Страна], Показатели в 2021, Показатели в 2022) VALUES ('" + region + "','" + country + "'," + in2021 + "," + in2022 + ")";
  OleDbCommand dbCommand = new OleDbCommand(query, dbConnection);
  dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
  dbConnection.Close();
```

Comment: А вы вопробуйте "Показатели в 2021, Показатели в 2022" перевделать в "[Показатели в 2021], [Показатели в 2022]" - или, лучше, вообще не использовать пробелы в именах полей. Как SQL это стерпел - ума не приложу...

Comment: 1. Какая ошибка появляется? Добавьте скриншот или сам текст ошибки в вопрос. 2. Используйте параметризированные запросы. (Подробнее: https://metanit.com/sharp/adonet/2.9.php) Это гораздо безопаснее и удобнее. Как минимум, исчезнет такая длинная колбасня, которая даже не влезает в экран (это я про строку `query`)

Comment: @Frehzy Насчёт первого вопроса, лучше именно текст, т.к. скриншоте не очень удобны (Было обсуждение на мете, лень искать)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Я пытаюсь через форму добавить в таблицу DataGridView1 новую запись. Она связана с бд Access base.mdb. При нажатии на кнопку добавления записи на форме должна появиться новая строка в DataGridView1 для заполнения(всего в таблице 4 колонки), но вместо этого возникает ошибка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы когда клеите SQL запрос из строк - меня прямо укачивает! И хочется написать в стиле C# 6.0:

```cs
    string query = $"INSERT INTO [Таблица] ([Регион], [Страна], [Показатели в 2021], [Показатели в 2022]) 
    VALUES ( '{region}', '{country}', {in2021}, {in2022} )";
```

Но, к сожалению, это не исправляет ситуацию, и всё остаётся так же уныло.

Хорошим варинатом был бы переход к так называемым параметризованным запросам, что Вам уже посоветовали, кажется, в первом же комментарии.

Приблизительно это выглядит так:

```cs
    string query = "INSERT INTO [Таблица] ([Регион], [Страна], [Показатели в 2021], [Показатели в 2022]) 
    VALUES ( @region, @country, @in2021, @in2022 )";

    OleDbCommand dbCommand = new OleDbCommand(query, dbConnection);

    dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@region", region);
    dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", country);
    dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@in2021", in2021);
    dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@in2022", in2022);
    dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    dbConnection.Close();
```

Видите, как всё изменилось? В строке запроса остались только формальные параметры. А потом Вы к этим параметрам "приставляете" значения. При этом гораздо меньше мест, в которых можно ошибиться.

Правда, есть еще мнение, что использование "AddWithValue" - это зло в чистом виде, и, возможно, этот метод вообще придуман самим Люцифером. На эту тему можете прочитать вот этот [ответ на вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1415998/). Но на том элементарном уровне, когда Вы выполняете простой `INSERT` в базу - Вас различие между `AddWithValue` и просто `Add` (метод, придуманный правильными пацанами) - не должно заботить.

Comment: Выглядит правда получше, но, к сожалению, проблему не решило

Comment: Ну, тогда давайте код создания таблицы, попробуем запустить это же у себя! Кстати, там хороший комментарий в другом ответе на вопрос, насчет точек и запятых в числах с плавающей точкой. Еще одна причина использовать параметризованные запросы!

Comment: Я создавал таблицу в Access и там же заполнял её. В винформе всего лишь подключился к ней(с этим проблем нет, там кода очень мало)

Comment: Измененный вариант уже работает, спасибо большое! Отныне буду использовать только параметризованные запросы в таких случаях)

Comment: Опять `AddWithValue`

Answer (score 1):

всегда заключайте наименования таблиц и их колонки в [], если они у вас с пробелами или не английские:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO [Таблица] ([Регион], [Страна], [Показатели в 2021], [Показатели в 2022]) VALUES ('" + region + "','" + country + "'," + in2021 + "," + in2022 + ")";
```

и лучше использовать параметризованный запрос, иначе возможны инъекции

Comment: Немного помогло, но теперь такая ошибка System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: "Не совпадает число значений запроса и число результирующих полей."

Comment: @Jolt Добавьте эту информацию в текст вопроса. И обязательно покажите полученное в переменной `query` значение после сборки.

Comment: описание таблицы требуется предоставить и используйте параметры, не собирайте строку запроса сами

Comment: Я кое-что заметил. Это значение query -- INSERT INTO [Таблица] ([Регион], [Страна], [Показатели в 2021], [Показатели в 2022]) VALUES('Азия', 'Япония', 2,2, 3,2 ). Вот эти последние цифры 2,2 и 3,2.. возможно, в них проблема? (в таблице у них формат одинарных в плавающей точкой)

Comment: ещё раз, используйте параметры, вам уже выше дали пример в другом ответе